# ListPlot a bunch of points that changes colour

Tags: plotting, color

I have a list of points:

```
r = Range[-Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/8];
angles = (c = Tuples[r, 2])
```

and a list of numbers which will determine the colour of the points above:

```
times = {12.5, 23.9, 3.7, 10.5, 6.7, 7.1, 20.2, 6.5, 11.7, 1.3, 29.8, 4.8, 
7.3, 19.5, 3.7, 19.3, 24.9, 11., 1.4, 6.6, 14.5, 23.2, 18.8, 23.2, 
17.1, 22.3, 5.2, Null, 7.5, 19.3, 23.5, 15.2, 17.6, 16.3, 11.7, Null, 
10.3, 13.6, 3.6, 3.4, 10., Null, Null, 25.5, 11.4, 4.9, 5.2, 24.3, 
9., 29.9, 7.5, Null, 9.1, 12.6, Null, 7.9, 13.2, 8.4, 9.8, Null, 20., 
24.3, 14.1, 3.7, 7.6, 18., 7.8, 8.8, 15.9, Null, 16.8, 13.3, 6.9, 
12.5, 3.3, 9.1, 7.1, 15.6, 9.5, 13.5, 12.1}
```

To turn these into colours, I do this:

```
colours = 
 times /. {x_ /; x < 3 -> Darker[Green], x_ /; 3 <= x < 6 -> Green, 
   x_ /; 6 <= x < 9 -> Darker[Red], x_ /; 9 <= x < 12 -> Red, 
   x_ /; 12 <= x < 20 -> Darker[Yellow], 
   x_ /; 20 <= x < 30 -> Lighter[Yellow], x_ /; 30 <= x -> White, 
   x_ /; x === Null -> White}
```

Now I want to plot `angles`, where the colour of each point is the based on the list `colours`.

This is what I tried:

```
ListLinePlot[angles, ColorFunction -> colours, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[.1]] /. Line -> Point
```

[image]

And that's not correct. It doesn't help that I am red-green colourblind so it's REALLY annoying. I've also fooled around with `ColorRules` and `MatrixPlot` but can't seem to get anything going. Any helpful hints or ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[Style[#, colours[[#2]], PointSize[.1]] &, angles], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

or

```
ListPlot[Style[#, #2, PointSize[.1]] & @@@ Transpose[{angles, colours}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

**Update:**

> *make those circles into squares, and make them all fill up the plot? As in no spaces between each one*

```
ArrayPlot[Transpose@Partition[colours, 9], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 DataReversed -> True, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. Do you know if there's a way in `ListPlot` to make those circles into squares, and make them all fill up the plot? As in no spaces between each one?

Comment: @LonelyMathematician, i think `ArrayPlot` is easier for this particular case: e.g., try `ArrayPlot[Transpose@Partition[colours, 9], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 DataReversed -> True]`.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to draw rectangles using `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[MapThread[{#2, Rectangle[#1, #1 + π/8]} &, {angles, colours}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]